# Can not use Vulkan Subgroup operations in Android Studio

Tags: android, math, vulkan, compute-shader, spir-v

I'm writing a Vulkan compute shader in Android studio and launching it on Android phone. The problem I'm experiencing is next - I can not use any subgroup operations like `subgroupAdd` and `subgroupElect`. When I'm trying to use these functions I have an error like this:

`reduce_vec.comp:35: error: 'subgroup op' : requires SPIR-V 1.3`

I have checked - my Android phone supports subgroups, and my shader accepts such extensions:

```
#extension GL_KHR_shader_subgroup_arithmetic: enable
#extension GL_KHR_shader_subgroup_basic: enable
```

The problem is pretty much straightforward, I need to update my SPIR-V. But according to my findings, SPIR-V that comes automatically with Android studio is not something I can update easily.

Did someone experience a similar issue before? What was your solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you got `android.hardware.vulkan.version` set to in your app manifest?

Comment: Hello! I didn't set this parameter to anything.. Should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android solution**

You can pass arguments to the Android shaderc compiler in your Gradle DSL:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/shader-compilers

You need `glslcArgs` to contain `--target-env=vulkan1.1`

**Flexible solution**

Build your own compilation pipeline to compile from source into SPIR-V, and then include the SPIR-V binary files directly into your Android project.

There are multiple language front-ends that can generate SPIR-V, for GLSL the Khronos tools are here:

- https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang

Comment: THat's what I'm working on right now. But I feel there're should be much easier option. I don't believe it has to be that complex

Comment: Updated to include an Android solution (not had a chance to test it yet, but works on the command line)

Comment: Your solution for Android studio is correct! Thank you very much for your help. Although it seems it has increased a build time of my project, but let's see, maybe it's just a lag